# Change Right-Click menu on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, right-click

I'm looking for a way to change the Right-Click context menu in Firefox using jQuery/CSS... and disable de default one of course.

I'm trying to make a Windows Explorer-like app to manage images and i want to be able to delete pictures using the right-click.

Anyone have an idea, cant find one.

Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot absolutely control the Firefox right-click menu.

Comment: This is bad practice. You shouldn't modify this functionality.

Comment: @Tyler: It's for a PHP Desktop application. Why I shouldn't do that?

Comment: @Tyler: It doesn't said why I shouldn't do that hehe... if you have any idea how i can make it easier than a right-click for a user to delete and rename files, go ahead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`oncontextmenu()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Careful though, users expect the default when they right click. It may annoy some power users.

[This](http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm) looks like good reading.

Comment: Don't worry it will run using Mozila Prism and it wil look like a real software but thanks for the advise.